# Python script that pings an internet server and let's you know when you are reconnected

Tags: python, if-statement, cmd, server, ping

I am trying to make a script that lets you know when a server connection is up and running again after going offline. I am using ping as a function in the `os.sytem` (so it runs in the clients cmd prompt). My thoughts was that if the result of the ping is positive, it will `print("!!! --servername-- is up and running again!!!")`. If the ping result is negative, the script should run the response() function again. Right now the ping function works, but the `if` statement with `result` does not give any output value.

```
import os
import time


ip_list = "8.8.8.8"
result = ()

if os.name == "nt":
    def response():
        os.system("ping -w 2s " + ip_list)
        return(result)
        #If the os name is nt (Windows), then the command should be as the above
else:
    def response():
        os.system("ping -i 2s " + ip_list)
        return(result)
        #If the os name is something else (Linux), then the command should be as the above

if result == 0:
    print (("!!! ") + ip_list + (" IS UP AND RUNNING AGAIN !!!"))
    #If the result of the ping is positive (== 0), then print the above message
elif result != 0:
    response()
    #If the result is not positive (not equal to 0), then do the ping function again
else:
    print(" ... ERROR ... ")
```

Also thinking about adding `time.sleep(20)` at the end so I have the time to view the eventually printed message.

Comment: You never change `result`, did you mean to do `result = os.system(...)`?

Comment: result can be equal `0` (`==`) or not equal `0` (`!=`) - there is no other option - so `else` will never be executed.

Comment: you should execute this funtion to `result = response()`. And it would be preferred to recreate function to send value to function `result = response(ip_list)`.

Comment: you will need `while`-loop insead of `if/else` - running again `response()` in if/elif will not check again result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few mistakes.

---

First: you have to assing result to variable

```
def response():
    result = os.system("ping -w 2s " + ip_list)
    return result
```

or you could use it directly with `return`

```
def response():
    return os.system("ping -w 2s " + ip_list)
```

---

Second: you have to run this function and get result

```
result = response()

if result == 0:
   # ... code ...
```

---

Third: it is preferred to send all values as arguments

```
def response(ip):
    return os.system("ping -w 2s " + ip)

result = response(ip_list)

if result == 0:
   # ... code ...
```

---

Fourth: `result` can be equal `0` or not equal `0` - there is no other option - so using `else` is useless

```
if result == 0:
    print (("!!! ") + ip_list + (" IS UP AND RUNNING AGAIN !!!"))
else:
    response()
```

---

Fifth: if you want it check again and again then you should use `while`-loop.

```
while True:
    result = response(ip_list)

    if result == 0:
        # if the result of the ping is positive (== 0), then print message
        print(("!!! ") + ip_list + (" IS UP AND RUNNING AGAIN !!!"))
        break  # exit loop
```

---

BTW: it is preferred to put comment in line beforeof code, not in line after code. Eventually at the end of line of code. And it is preferred to put single space after `#` (and two space before `#` when it is in the same line.)

See more: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

```
import os
import time

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: functions before main code

if os.name == "nt":
    def response(ip):
        # if the os name is nt (Windows)
        return os.system("ping -w 2s " + ip)
else:
    def response(ip):
        # if the os name is something else (Linux)
        return os.system("ping -i 2s " + ip)

# --- main ---

ip_list = "8.8.8.8"

while True:
    result = response(ip_list)

    if result == 0:
        # if the result of the ping is positive (== 0), then print message
        #print("!!! " + ip_list + " IS UP AND RUNNING AGAIN !!!")  # there is no need to put string in `( )`
        print(f"!!! {ip_list} IS UP AND RUNNING AGAIN !!!")  # f-string can be more readable.
        break  # exit loop
    
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Wow this helped a lot, thank you so much! I am very new to Python, and I absolutely agree that the code looks so much easier to understand with the tips that you wrote. The code worked just the way I wanted it to, so thank you so much!